# Given f(3) = 4 and f ′(3) = 5 , find g′(3) where g(x) = 5x/f(x)

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

Comment: We have $g(x)=\frac{5x}{f(x)}$. Use the Quotient Rule to obtain an expression for $g'(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Comment: once you do that, don't forget to plug $3$ for $x$ in $g'(x)$, to obtain the answer for $g'(3)$

Answer (score 3):

Use the quotient rule.

$$g'(x) = \frac{f(x) \cdot (5x)' - f'(x) \cdot 5x}{(f(x))^2}$$

This gives you

$$g'(3) = \frac{5f(3) - 15f'(3)}{(f(3))^2} = \frac{20 - 75}{16}.$$

Comment: $g'(x)\not= g'(3)$

Comment: so g'(x) would = 5f(x)-5f'(x)/(f(x))^2 ? and then just plug g'(3) into the function

Comment: That's exactly it. By that I mean you plug 3 in the place of $x$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But what is the purpose then of being given f(3) = 4 and f'(3) = 5 if they're not needed to solve this problem?

Comment: You need it because when you plug in 3, you are plugging it into $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ which are part of the equation.

Comment: I've filled it out for you.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thanks again!